# How to read a map from Firestore in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have a map called Statistics and I want to retrieve it's data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Reference to the snapshot
DocumentReference docRef = database.Collection("Users").Document("document");
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await docRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
//Create a variable that sets the document data as a dictionary
Dictionary<string, object> user = snapshot.ToDictionary();
//Create and declare a new variable that will only take the nested dictionary, in this case 
//it's called "Statistics"
Dictionary<string, object> statistics = new Dictionary<string, object> { };
statistics = (Dictionary<string, object>)user["Statistics"];
//Read the nested dictionary :)
foreach (var key in statistics)
{
    Debug.Log(key.Key + "\t\t" + key.Value);
}
```

[image: Result]